# Application crashes when pressing the button when switching to a fragment and back again

Tags: android, kotlin

Why is it that when I go from the home slice to another slice and then back to the home slice and when I click on the hitButton, the application crashes.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var score = 0
    private lateinit var scoreTextView: TextView
    private var pelmen:Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        scoreTextView = findViewById(R.id.scoreTextView)
        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            score = savedInstanceState.getInt("score")
            scoreTextView.text = "счёт: $score"
        }

        val hitButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.hitButton)
        hitButton.setOnClickListener {
            score++
            scoreTextView.text = "счёт: $score"
            val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, R.raw.punch)
            mediaPlayer.start()

            val imageView: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.sergayView)
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.malyshanim)

            if (score == 50) {
                scoreTextView.text = "вы получили новый уровень!"
            }

            Handler().postDelayed({
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.malysh)
            }, 200)
        }
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putInt("score", score)
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        score = savedInstanceState.getInt("score")
        scoreTextView.text = "счёт: $score"
    }
}
```

I would like to know how to solve this problem

Comment: Could you share your stacktrace, and also I suggest you to initialize widgets using binding while you have using binding, instead of using like this `val hitButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.hitButton)` you can use `val hitButton: Button = binding.hitButton` while using View Binding

Comment: You need to share the stacktrack for crashes. Also, explain what a "slice" is.